# jQuery error when attempting to edit custom filter

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

On the SE.com site, affecting my global *[Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters)*, if I attempt to click the **edit** link, the JavaScript console reports an error:

> TypeError: $.browser is undefined[Learn More] jquery.autocomplete.min.js:11:1270

Same error on Firefox and Safari running on MacOS.

On Chrome latest version under Windows 7 the error is:

> jquery.autocomplete.min.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opera' of undefined(…)

Comment: Same when trying to add tags to new filter, at least with Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was caused by an outdated jQuery autocomplete plugin - we've updated jQuery but not the plugin, which started breaking.

We have now updated the plugin, so the page is back in operating condition.